# Using OrmLite's Select with F#

Tags: f#, ormlite-servicestack

I am considering OrmLite to as a .NET replacement for PonyORM (python) for rewriting my web project.

I am using F#, and I am struggling a bit with the syntax of the linq like query syntax.

The C# examples is something like:

```cs
db.Select<User>(u => u.Name).PrintDump();
```

which I have tried to mimic with

```
db.Select<User>(fun (u:SqlExpression<_>) -> u.Name).PrintDump()
```

but I get an error: 'Name is not defined'.

**What is the correct syntax?**

The following does produce an output of everything:

```
db.Select<User>(fun (u:SqlExpression<_>) -> u).PrintDump()
```

gives

```
[
  {
    Date: 2014-10-25,
    Name: "Jason"
  }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those errors because your types do not match.

```
db.Select<User>(fun (u:SqlExpression<_>) -> u.Name)
```

In this case `u` is not a user object, it is a `SqlExpression` which is a class in OrmLite. If you check your intellisense you'll see that it has quite a lot of methods, but none of them are `Name`.

I'm betting that what you want to do is actually something like this

```
db.Select(db.From<User>().Select(fun (u : User) -> u.Name)
```

In this case the inner thing is actually a `SqlExpression<User>` which is what OrmLite expects.